# Warning 6011 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I do not understand the meaning if this warning I get. My code compiles but fails to read `inputs` half of the time.

```
typedef struct a
{
    double* inputs;
} A;
```

I create a new struct A:

```
A* createA(double* inputs) 
{
    A* a = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
    a->inputs = inputs;
}
```

Why do I get the `6011` warning on `a->inputs = inputs;`?

On the Microsoft Documentation it says to test if the given argument is `NULL` before feeding `a->inputs`, witch is indeed a good practice to track errors.

But even adding:

```
A* createA(double* inputs) 
{
    A* a = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
    if (inputs != NULL)
        a->inputs = inputs;
    else /* error */
}
```

I still get the warning but on the `if` statement.

Comment: I believe the warning is referring to the variable `a`, not `inputs`, ie. you are not handling the case when the allocation fails. But why are you using `malloc` instead of `new` in c++?

Comment: `if (inputs != NULL) a->inputs = inputs; ` - don't you want to test `a` rather than (or in addition to) `inputs`? Also; don't use `malloc` in C++. And prefer `nullptr` over `NULL`.

Comment: @clcto I'm a beginner in c++, I mostly learned C. Old habit. I also should create a Class for A. And you are right about `a`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @clcto explained, it is because you are not doing error checking.

If you do not care about OOM, and you can use exceptions, simply do:

```
struct A
{
    double* inputs;
};

A* createA(double* inputs) 
{
    A* a = new A;
    a->inputs = inputs;
    return a;
}
```

Because `new` will throw on OOM. If you cannot use exceptions and/or want to check the return value instead, look into using `new(std::nothrow)`.

Also note the notation on `struct A`, instead of a `typedef` (unneeded in C++). Also, you should probably look into using `std::unique_ptr<A>` instead, too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `malloc` may return `NULL` when it fails. In this case, writing to `a->inputs` in the following line would be dereferencing the `NULL` pointer, which is Undefined Behavior, and should be avoided. It's admittedly unlikely that `malloc` will fail, but since you like to write safe code, you should be testing the return value of `malloc`:

```
A* a = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
if (a != NULL){
    a->inputs = inputs;
} else {
    /* Handle error */
}
```

---

Since you're writing C++ coming from a C background, you should be aware that the code you're writing is essentially still C, and is very different from modern C++, in which we do lots of things very differently. In C++, there are lots of very helpful tools and idioms we like to use.

I'm assuming that `inputs` is a list of numbers. In C++, I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
// no typedef
struct A {
    vector<double> inputs;
};

// no createA

// Example usage:
int main(){
    A a;

    // no manual memory management!!!

    // no pointers!

    // how many inputs?
    cout << "There are " << a.inputs.size() << " inputs\n";

    // add two inputs
    a.inputs.push_back(3.83);
    a.inputs.push_back(1.01);

    // print everything
    for (const auto& input : a.inputs){
        cout << input << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This how we usually do things in C++ nowadays. There's lots of things going on under the hood, but the overall experience is very safe and friendly once you know what you're doing. If you're interested, I would suggest that you take your pick from [this list of good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read carefully. Otherwise, it might be simplest to stick to C, if that's what you're comfortable with.

Answer (score -3):

There is a memory problem in your case, because in the struct a, there is the pointer inputs.

inputs is not assign. You must allocate some memory a make inputs point to it OR you must assign NULL to it, in a constructor for example (yes, you can add a constructor to a struct in C++.)

Comment: I do feed `createA` with an allocated `double*`. The problem was not checking if `a` was `NULL` at it's creation.

Comment: may be there is a confusion between two different inputs : the one inside the class and the other as function argument. Could you try to change one of them ?

Comment: Thanks for contributing! I'm having some trouble understanding your answer though. This isn't a problem about what the member `input` is pointing to, but rather about dereferencing `a` after allocating it. Also, note that constructors won't be called by `malloc`, so this answer is a bit incomplete.